# Getting E0800 in Oozie logs

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, cloudera, oozie

I am running an Oozie job with four subworkflows. For testing purposes, I am using a Cloudera VM. Though the job output is fine, I am getting the following XException in my Oozie logs:

2015-02-26 02:26:58,934 WARN org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper: SERVER[quickstart.cloudera] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] exception callable [callback], E0800: Action it is not running its in [PREP] state, action [0000003-150226014822163-oozie-oozi-W@midso-chat-data-Decrypt]
org.apache.oozie.command.CommandException: E0800: Action it is not running its in [PREP] state, action [0000003-150226014822163-oozie-oozi-W@midso-chat-data-Decrypt]

This is happening when I pass parameters to the sub workflows explicitly through the main worlflow, rather than using  tag. However, these XExceptions do not show up when I run each sub workflow independently of y the main workflow.

Does anyone have any leads on this?

Comment: This isn't the actual error - the real one will be elsewhere. If the issue is within a sub-workflow, have a look at the sub-workflow's logs (I presume the logs you posted are for the parent workflow). Or if the workflow managed to kick off an action which died, have a look in its logs in JobBrowser.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if Oozie has subworkflow logs avalibale? Or should I check Yarn.

Comment: You can check the same way from command line.

`oozie job -log [sub wf-id]`

the sub wf-id can be found by the command

`oozie job -info [master-wfid]`

It is displayed in the Ext Id column.

Comment: oozie is garbage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you missed the propagate-configuration tag in the workflow:

```
    <sub-workflow>
    <app-path>/app/oozie/src/main/DailyWorkflow/subworkflows/TableAA</app-path>
    <propagate-configuration/>
    </sub-workflow>
```

and in the sub-workflow you could probably see an error that the subworkflow action couldn't find parameters that were not propagated to it.